# How do I solve an overdetermined linear system of partial differential equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, partial-differential-equations, finite-differences

I have two partial differential equations that I want to solve (for $\ \sigma $) by finite differences:
$\ -\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x}(x,y,t) -p(x,y,t)\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t}(x,y,t) = p(x,y,t)$

$\ -\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial y}(x,y,t) -q(x,y,t)\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t}(x,y,t) = q(x,y,t)$

where p and q are known.

This is an over determined system (one unknown, two equations) so I am seeking an Least Squares Error (LSE) solution.

I know that for the inversion problem:

$\ d = \mathbf{F}m $

, where F is a forward operator,
the LSE is:

$\ \mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{F}m = \mathbf{F}^Td$

In my case $\ \mathbf{d}=[p(x,y,t),q(x,y,t)]^T$, $\ \mathbf{m} = [\sigma] $ and 
$\ \mathbf{F} =[-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-p\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, -\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-q\frac{\partial}{\partial t}]^T$ ?

How do I solve this by finite differences?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

EDIT:

Thanks to Andrew we can instead solve the easier equation:

$\ qs_x=ps_y $

for each discrete t value.

I have m discrete x values: $\ x_i, 1<=i<=m $ and n discrete y values: $\ y_j, 1<=j<=n $.

My boundary condition is:

$\ s(m/2,n/2)=t $

I could of course just integrate outwards from the center point, but this would yield a different result depending on the path taken.

Therefore I am looking for a LSE solution to this equation.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be simplified a bit. Putting $s(x,y,t)=\sigma(x,y,t)+t$ turns  the system into a homogeneous one:
$$
-s_x-ps_t=0,
$$
$$
-s_y-qs_t=0.
$$
Excluding $s_t$ we have $qs_x=ps_y\;$.

Comment: But how do I find the LSE for this?

Comment: There is at least one exact solution $s\equiv0$ or $\sigma\equiv-t$. Besides for concrete $p$, $q$ it is possible to try to find exact solutions (if any) by the characteristics method and then substitute the general solution into one of the equations.

Comment: For $qs_x=ps_y\;$, $s(x,x)=t\;$ the solution is $s(x,y)=t$.